# LaTeX Beamer Presentation Template Modifications

Tags: beamer, pdftex, templates, presentations, beamerarticle

I was trying to make a customized Beamer Presentation template but I failed to make it complete and facing some difficulties to finalize it. May you help me to make it complete the task..

My coding is given below

```
    \documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}
    \usetheme{Darmstadt}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    %\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
    \useoutertheme[subsection=false,footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
    \usefonttheme{serif}
    \usepackage{palatino}

    \setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
    \setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}

    \setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=DeepSkyBlue4} 
    \setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
    \setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 
    \setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black} 
    \setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=DeepSkyBlue4,bg=white} 

    \setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
    \setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

    \renewcommand{\(}{\begin{columns}}
    \renewcommand{\)}{\end{columns}}
    \newcommand{\<}[1]{\begin{column}{#1}}
    \renewcommand{\>}{\end{column}}

    \title{Fundamentals of X and Y}
    \subtitle{Tutorial at Z 2009, Vienna, Austria}
    \author{Gsomething Ksomething}
    \institute{Department of Electrical Engineering \\ University of Something Comething}

    \newcommand{\makeasection}{%
    \subsection{A} % force dots to show up below section navigation
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    Frame content
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    Frame content
    \end{frame}
    }
    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \section{Channels, Coding, and Capacity} \makeasection
    \section{Spectral Efficiency} \makeasection
    \section{Linear Block Codes} \makeasection
    \section{Hard and Soft Decoding} \makeasection
    \section{Fiber Capacity Estimate} \makeasection
    \subsection{Blocks}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Blocks}
    \begin{definition}[Greetings]
    Hello World
    \end{definition}

    \begin{theorem}[Fermat's Last Theorem]
    $a^n + b^n = c^n, n \leq 2$
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{alertblock}{Alert Block}
    Errors!
    \end{alertblock}

    \begin{exampleblock}{Example Block}
    An example of something.
    \end{exampleblock}

    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Now I want to remove the header part from the first page and add two logo file on top and one at the bottom corner (mentioned in the sample image [image: figure])

The footer should be similar to the the attached file (color may be different) but should include the page information[image: Footer]

The title pages (from 2nd page onwards) should have a logo in left portion of the title and the background color should be blue color gradient (explained in the attached figure). [image: Page inside]

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the things you want are non-standard in beamer. But you can always take the existing beamer templates as starting point and tweak the according to your needs

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false,footline=authortitle]{miniframes}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{palatino}

\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}

\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=DeepSkyBlue4} 
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=DeepSkyBlue4,bg=white} 

\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title{Fundamentals of X and Y}
\subtitle{Tutorial at Z 2009, Vienna, Austria}
\author{Gsomething Ksomething}
\institute{Department of Electrical Engineering \\ University of Something Comething}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% footline mod. from beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=black,bg=}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
    \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
        \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{0cm}%
            \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}%
            \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{3.5ex}}%
            \pgfusepath{clip}%
            \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}%
        \end{pgfpicture}%
    \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by 0.95ex%
    \vskip-\beamer@tempdim%
    \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }  
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% titlepage mod. from beamerinnerthemedefault.sty
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
    \vbox{}
    \begingroup
    \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-grid-100x100bp}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-grid-100x100bp}\par
        \vskip1em\par
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]{title}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
        \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
        \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
        \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]{author}
        \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]{institute}
        \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]{date}
        \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
    \hfill 
    \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-grid-100x100bp}\par
    \endgroup
    \vfill
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% framtitle mod. from beamerouterthemeshadow.sty
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\colorlet{titleright}{yellow!10!white}
\colorlet{titleleft}{DeepSkyBlue4}
\colorlet{titlemid}{green!60!blue}

\makeatletter

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[titleleft,titleright]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
        color(0pt)=(titleleft);
        color(.5\paperwidth)=(titlemid);
        color(\paperwidth)=(titleright)
}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{\paperwidth}{%
        color(0pt)=(bg);
        color(4pt)=(black!50!bg)    
    }
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip-2pt%
    \hbox{\leavevmode
        \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
        \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
        \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
        \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
            \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
                    \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
                    \leftskip0.3cm%
                    \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
                    \insertframetitle \hfill \raisebox{-0.8mm}{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{example-grid-100x100bp}}%
                    \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
                    \strut\par%
                    \else
                    \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
                    \fi%
                    \nointerlineskip
                    \vbox{}%
                \end{minipage}}%
                \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
                \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
                \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
                    \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
                    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
                    \pgfusepath{clip}
                    \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
                \end{pgfpicture}
                \hskip-\paperwidth%
                \box\beamer@tempbox%
            }%
            \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
        }%
        \nointerlineskip
        \vskip-0.2pt
        \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
        \vskip-2pt
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{test}
\subsection{test}

\begin{frame}{test}
    test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to make the color ramp from dark to lighter (just the opposite of given one)

Comment: Define the colour accordingly: ` \colorlet{titleleft}{yellow!10!white}
    \colorlet{titleright}{blue!50!black}
    \colorlet{titlemid}{green!60!blue}`

Comment: Can I put similar type of color format for footer ? Thanks you :)

Comment: Yes, you can. You have to modify what is inside `\setbeamertemplate{footline}`. Have a look at  the frametitle to see how `\pgfuseshading` is used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. If you modify the footer then plz look into the frametitle logo and if possible plz make it centralized vertically. Thank you once again :)

Comment: @ibrahimkbd see edit. Depending on the image ratio, you might have to adjust a few numbers.